# Not Seeing SlimDX in "Add Reference" Visual Studio 2012 tab

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference, addition, slimdx

I'm trying to get SlimDX up and I'm following their tutorial  [here.](http://slimdx.org/tutorials/BasicWindow.php) Under project settings it shows how to add a reference to SlimDX but when I follow they're steps I don't have SlimDX in my options. I've tried reinstalling the SDK a few times and it hasn't helped. I'm pretty new to C# and Visual Studio so excuse me if it's a small user error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newer installations don't add SlimDX to the GAC, so it doesn't show up in the reference windows.

You should be able to browse to their installation folder, and pick the assembly directly.  This will add the reference, and copy it locally on build (by default).

Comment: Ok thanks. That's just the .dll in the right directory for my OS in the bin right?

Answer (score 0):

For those who look for the direct directory (obviously only after installation).
That's for the .Net v4 (from: https://slimdx.org/download.php)

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\SlimDX
or:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\SlimDX

I looked for That for the last hour++